# How to insert all styles of a document in current document using 'insertFileFromBase64' in word add-in

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-addins, office-js

I am developing a word add-in using word javascript api. I need to fetch the documents from sever and insert into current document in MS Word.

Currently i am using below code to insert the document:

```
// Create a proxy object for the default selection. 
 var mySelection = thisDocument.getSelection();
// Queue a command to insert the file into the current document.
 mySelection.insertFileFromBase64(myBase64, "replace");
```

but it inserted the document with Single style, as i have multiple styles saved with document that i need to insert.

Please guide me how i can insert the document with its all styles in current Word Document.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is a by design behavior, if styles from the same name are already in use in the document you are inserting the file to, Word does not override the existing style definitions. 
Couple of options you have is to change the style names, you can also try to insert the OOXML of the document and make sure the style definitions on the ooxml are unique.

Please check out this example on inserting a document with its own style definitions. (to restore the doc simply decode the base64 and see the styles created there)

```js
    function insertFileDiffStyle() {
        Word.run(function (context) {
            var mybase64 = getBase64Bis();
            context.document.body.insertFileFromBase64(mybase64, "end");
            return context.sync();

        })


    }

    function getBase64Bis() {

        return ("UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQDfpNJsWgEAACAFAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAAC AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0 lMtuwjAQRfeV+g+Rt1Vi6KKqKgKLPpYtUukHGHsCVv2Sx7z+vhMCUVUBkQpsIiUz994zVsaD0dqa bAkRtXcl6xc9loGTXmk3K9nX5C1/ZBkm4ZQw3kHJNoBsNLy9GUw2ATAjtcOSzVMKT5yjnIMVWPgA jiqVj1Ykeo0zHoT8FjPg973eA5feJXApT7UHGw5eoBILk7LXNX1uSCIYZNlz01hnlUyEYLQUiep8 6dSflHyXUJBy24NzHfCOGhg/mFBXjgfsdB90NFEryMYipndhqYuvfFRcebmwpCxO2xzg9FWlJbT6 2i1ELwGRztyaoq1Yod2e/ygHpo0BvDxF49sdDymR4BoAO+dOhBVMP69G8cu8E6Si3ImYGrg8Rmvd CZFoA6F59s/m2NqciqTOcfQBaaPjP8ber2ytzmngADHp039dm0jWZ88H9W2gQB3I5tv7bfgDAAD/ /wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQAekRq37wAAAE4CAAALAAgCX3JlbHMvLnJlbHMgogQCKKAAAgAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAArJLBasMw DEDvg/2D0b1R2sEYo04vY9DbGNkHCFtJTBPb2GrX/v082NgCXelhR8vS05PQenOcRnXglF3wGpZV DYq9Cdb5XsNb+7x4AJWFvKUxeNZw4gyb5vZm/cojSSnKg4tZFYrPGgaR+IiYzcAT5SpE9uWnC2ki Kc/UYySzo55xVdf3mH4zoJkx1dZqSFt7B6o9Rb6GHbrOGX4KZj+xlzMtkI/C3rJdxFTqk7gyjWop 9SwabDAvJZyRYqwKGvC80ep6o7+nxYmFLAmhCYkv+3xmXBJa/ueK5hk/Nu8hWbRf4W8bnF1B8wEA AP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhANZks1H0AAAAMQMAABwACAF3b3JkL19yZWxzL2RvY3VtZW50Lnht bC5yZWxzIKIEASigAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAArJLLasMwEEX3hf6DmH0t O31QQuRsSiHb1v0ARR4/qCwJzfThv69ISevQYLrwcq6Yc8+ANtvPwYp3jNR7p6DIchDojK971yp4 qR6v7kEQa1dr6x0qGJFgW15ebJ7Qak5L1PWBRKI4UtAxh7WUZDocNGU+oEsvjY+D5jTGVgZtXnWL cpXndzJOGVCeMMWuVhB39TWIagz4H7Zvmt7ggzdvAzo+UyE/cP+MzOk4SlgdW2QFkzBLRJDnRVZL itAfi2Myp1AsqsCjxanAYZ6rv12yntMu/rYfxu+wmHO4WdKh8Y4rvbcTj5/oKCFPPnr5BQAA//8D AFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEA0B4o99wCAAAxCwAAEQAAAHdvcmQvZG9jdW1lbnQueG1s1JZtb5swEMff T9p3QLxvDYSkLWpSbU1bddKkaOleT45xwAu2kW2SZp9+Zx5CKvpAkjebFAWMz7/7n+/McX3zzDNn TZVmUoxd/9xzHSqIjJlIxu7Pp/uzS9fRBosYZ1LQsbul2r2ZfP50vYliSQpOhXEAIXS0ycnYTY3J I4Q0SSnH+pwzoqSWS3NOJEdyuWSEoo1UMQo83yvvciUJ1Rr83WKxxtqtceS5Hy1WeAOLLTBEJMXK 0OeW4R8MGaIrdNkFBUeAIMLA76IGB6NGyKrqgMKjQKCqQxoeR+oEx7slIHMqYHIpFccGhipBHKtV kZ8BOMeGLVjGzBaY3qjByLFbKBHViLOdFrskqrTUl2aF6uO3WjKty7b0iBTNQIMUOmX5rvb4sTSY TBvI+r0g1jxr7Da53zORbx2caZWWFthHfp1LnlXK3yf6Xo+MWMRuRR8JL302SjhmonV81Nbsba7f s7QbQNABjDQ9DDGsEUhveXs0NnlyWpYflCzylsZOoz2K1Y5l3+sHsOpq2a9gfZqYeYpzOMqcRI+J kAovMlAEuXcgfU6ZAceeEncCXWch46295s4mgq4V/xi7nncbhHcedKr60ZQucZEZO3MVhlfToJmZ 7T0qITNVXuZmm4GPaI2zsfutwIJm0nfR5BrtbMo/M3lKmXbg50A3hMYIy6yNKS1VZd9R91JDP3Xo H6K8uVO/q50q/by5U1hIk1LlLLLiP9ixj6pi8H6sjkmZiqE6FBaJDffjWMPBxZf7V1W+nDlB5ULK lW26cwPdGkxZDCzLFZjDSfv1IL9isqp2sLG9E/HOsobZaU2JmalX9JdakvkfmIKXvx8EYekhhfvh ZVgyrMF3bBcbCT3KDysTxZLUtMOFNEbydpzR5d5sSnFModtfBOVwKaXZGyaFKYe1OyIzDU91jgmt bMrH8OH6oJgNL2OCzpghoHIwauKsQixvq5cNar91J38BAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBmOrwU JAYAAI8aAAAVAAAAd29yZC90aGVtZS90aGVtZTEueG1s7FlNixs3GL4X+h+GuTse2zP+WOIN47Gd tNlNQnaTkqM8I88o1oyMJO+uCYGSnHopFNLSQwO99VBKAw009NIfs5DQpj+iksZjj2y5S7oOhNI1 rPXxvK8eva/0SOO5eu0sxdYJpAyRrGvXrji2BbOQRCiLu/a942GlbVuMgywCmGSwa88hs6/tf/zR VbDHE5hCS9hnbA907YTz6V61ykLRDNgVMoWZ6BsTmgIuqjSuRhScCr8prtYdp1lNAcpsKwOpcHt7 PEYhtI6lS3u/cD7A4l/GmWwIMT2SrqFmobDRpCa/2JwFmFonAHdtMU5ETo/hGbctDBgXHV3bUX92 df9qdWmE+Rbbkt1Q/S3sFgbRpK7saDxaGrqu5zb9pX8FwHwTN2gNmoPm0p8CgDAUM8256D5b9cBd YEugvGjw3W/1GzUNX/Lf2MD7nvxoeAXKi+4GfjgMVjEsgfKit4H3ep1eX/evQHmxuYFvOX7fbWl4 BUowyiYbaMdrNoJitkvImOAbRnjHc4et+gK+QlVLqyu3z/i2tZaCh4QOBUAlF3CUWXw+hWMQClwA MBpRZB2gOBELbwoywkSzU3eGTkP8lx9XlVRGwR4EJeu8KWQbTZKPxUKKprxrfyq82iXI61evzp+8 PH/y6/nTp+dPfl6MvWl3A2Rx2e7tD1/99fxz689fvn/77GsznpXxb3764s1vv/+Te67R+ubFm5cv Xn/75R8/PjPAfQpGZfgxSiGzbsFT6y5JxQQNA8ARfTeL4wSgsoWfxQxkQNoY0AOeaOhbc4CBAdeD ehzvUyEXJuD12UON8FFCZxwZgDeTVAMeEoJ7hBrndFOOVY7CLIvNg9NZGXcXgBPT2MFalgezqVj3 yOQySKBG8w4WKQcxzCC3ZB+ZQGgwe4CQFtdDFFLCyJhbD5DVA8gYkmM00lbTyugGSkVe5iaCIt9a bA7vWz2CTe778ERHir0BsMklxFoYr4MZB6mRMUhxGXkAeGIieTSnoRZwxkWmY4iJNYggYyab23Su 0b0pZMac9kM8T3Uk5WhiQh4AQsrIPpkECUinRs4oS8rYT9hELFFg3SHcSILoO0TWRR5AtjXd9xHU 0n3x3r4nZMi8QGTPjJq2BCT6fpzjMYDKeXVN11OUXSjya/LuvT95FyL6+rvnZs3dgaSbgZcRc58i 425al/BtuHXhDgiN0Iev230wy+5AsVUM0P9l+3/Z/s/L9rb9vHuxXumzusgX13XlJt16dx8jjI/4 HMMDppSdielFQ9GoKspo+agwTURxMZyGiylQZYsS/hniyVECpmKYmhohZgvXMbOmhImzQTUbfcsO PEsPSZS31mrF06kwAHzVLs6Wol2cRDxvbbZWj2FL96oWq8flgoC0fRcSpcF0Eg0DiVbReAEJNbOd sOgYWLSl+60s1NciK2L/WUD+sOG5OSOx3gCGkcxTbl9kd+eZ3hZMfdp1w/Q6kutuMq2RKC03nURp GSYgguvNO851Z5VSjZ4MxSaNVvt95FqKyJo24EyvWadizzU84SYE0649FrdCUUynwh+TuglwnHXt kC8C/W+UZUoZ7wOW5DDVlc8/RRxSC6NUrPVyGnC24lart+QcP1ByHefDi5z6KicZjscw5FtaVlXR lzsx9l4SLCtkJkgfJdGpNcIzeheIQHmtmgxghBhfRjNCtLS4V1Fck6vFVtR+NVttUYCnCVicKGUx z+GqvKRTmodiuj4rvb6YzCiWSbr0qXuxkewoieaWA0Semmb9eH+HfInVSvc1Vrl0r2tdp9C6bafE 5Q+EErXVYBo1ydhAbdWqU9vhhaA03HJpbjsjdn0arK9aeUAU90pV23g9QUYPxcrvi+vqDHOmqMIz 8YwQFD8s50qgWgt1OePWjKKu/cjxfDeoe0HFaXuDittwnUrb8xsV3/MatYFXc/q9+mMRFJ6kNS8f eyieZ/B88fZFtW+8gUmLa/aVkKRVou7BVWWs3sDU6tvfwFhIROZRsz7sNDq9ZqXT8IcVt99rVzpB s1fpN4NWf9gPvHZn+Ni2ThTY9RuB2xy0K81aEFTcpiPptzuVlluv+27Lbw9c//Ei1mLmxXcRXsVr /28AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCejGvL0AMAADUKAAARAAAAd29yZC9zZXR0aW5ncy54bWy0 Vm1v2zgM/n7A/YfAny+N49pJaiwd1qS5dWi2Yc5+gGzJiVC9QZKTZsP996Nkq07X3ZDdsE+W+JAP KYqk/Or1I2eDPdGGSjGPxhdxNCCikpiK7Tz6vFkNZ9HAWCQwYlKQeXQkJnp9/ecfrw65IdaCmhkA hTA5r+bRzlqVj0am2hGOzIVURABYS82Rha3ejjjSD40aVpIrZGlJGbXHURLHk6ijkfOo0SLvKIac VloaWVtnksu6phXpPsFCn+O3NVnKquFEWO9xpAmDGKQwO6pMYOP/lw3AXSDZ/+gQe86C3mEcn3Hc g9T4yeKc8JyB0rIixsAFcRYCpKJ3nL4gevJ9Ab67I3oqMB/HfnUaefZzBMkLgokhP0eRdRQjc+Tk MRAZdk5KWuielhrptuC6fPAqv9sKqVHJIBzIywCONvDRRddQ5V+k5INDroiu4KqhReI4GjkAEizr wiJLADaKMOZ7pmIEAe0h32rEodqDxNtgUqOG2Q0qCysVKO0RRD9NOspqhzSqLNGFQhWwLaSwWrKg h+V7aRfQORoutrPwfdSvirYnwUIgDud51mdriYmLrNH0/MQ7A+99nJ26/NaRhBmiKSYbl8fCHhlZ QfAF/ULeCPyuMZYCo++2X4jgRwEQ4Tx/gJvfHBVZEWQbSNNvcuZvYsWoWlOtpb4TGGrjtzmjdU00 OKBQa2soH6rlwef5LUEYRvcv+h2dlhE8BNiExScpbVCN46s0vVombaQO7ZH0cvpm9V3kv20WSXob zzr/nVeeuyH6UYeVK6EBby0WiJeaosHajdmR0yj1ww0VAS8JtDs5RYqmDOBw2AKGI8ZW0GMB8I3H c0yNWpLar9ka6W3P22no70qhn989cbn5QPTfWjaqRQ8aqbY0gso4TTtLKuw95UFumrIIVgIG1AnU CPxhr32e+vQccgtX7FvsHvlS8bpEDD8XXSkxXbgyIGukVFtN5XY8jxjd7uzYFYCFHYbX2G/KbdJh iceSFvMbVLmTgXa36GVJkJ3oXQbZZS9LgyztZVmQZb1sEmQTJ9tBH2sYqg9Q2GHp5LVkTB4Iftvj L0RtEswOKbJsZy6Ul2wF3RA2g31OHmGiE0wt/OQoijl6dAM+mTjzTpuho2zsM12HOWX1nAEji0JL PTP2Jf5NLO4tqCiUY3HkZT/iL9rAGTUwBhS8BlbqgP3lsXGaY1ndQSfBysuz1dVqOYunLZz5V8Ru oMgf4N4/kfoGGYI7LJhmrenXeDKeZTerm2F2e3s5TCeTq+Esg+1NslhMb7PJYjmd/dM1afjfu/4X AAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCklWIcVgIAAHAIAAASAAAAd29yZC9mb250VGFibGUueG1svJVt b9owEMffT9p3sPy+xEmgPKihAgbSpK0vpu4DGOMQq7Ed2YaUb7+zE1hVykqqbbEUhTv7n7sfd5e7 +2dZoj03VmiV4bhHMOKK6Y1Q2wz/fFzdjDCyjqoNLbXiGT5wi++nnz/d1ZNcK2cRnFd2IlmGC+eq SRRZVnBJbU9XXIEz10ZSBz/NNpLUPO2qG6ZlRZ1Yi1K4Q5QQcotbGXONis5zwfgXzXaSKxfOR4aX oKiVLURlj2r1NWq1NpvKaMathZxl2ehJKtRJJu6fCUnBjLY6dz1Ipo0oSMHxmIQnWf4WGHQTSM4E bi3vJjFoJSJ7kPwZI8kmX7dKG7ouQQlSQhAVCsJ42v6ZqJ4oKsG9oKVYGxEcFVXa8hh8e1pmmCRk RQZw96tPUn/Hkd/ICmos9yLNRtKYcypFeThabS2sbRyVcKw42vfUCB9a47JiC46dXZMMLwlcyWqF G0uc4T4YZouTJfHvClfcWtKThXgLCzrNjnE4xYLOaQ+8M2oInJF4FJJb9MBr9ENLqi4QScgtkBgA D08m7UTEBN2uRJLlSyILsAxH/fSMyPh9Io3O9URmEFaJ5iVlTxdozMkMSPg+aKvkn9bHzAeczF7V x3C0mp/RCLn/kQbpWh9zuivozqJx+iYM3yDjUBTzgGJBkg4wNpxBwzqxb9O+kkgb9rEaXmbyASJN V11P5LtW2h0qjhYaPip7+iaXFIqjWb5MwupSJMyIynVnkoyGf4dJ1ypp5yn6JraFuzhV/Sz9X1O1 6Zrlq65JyPAjXfP+VG0f7PQXAAAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAk3bWSRgBAABAAgAAFAAAAHdv cmQvd2ViU2V0dGluZ3MueG1slNHBSgMxEAbgu+A7hNzbbIstsnRbEKl4EUF9gDSdbYOZTMikbuvT O65VES/tLZNkPuZnZos9BvUGmT3FRo+GlVYQHa193DT65Xk5uNaKi41rGyhCow/AejG/vJh1dQer JyhFfrISJXKNrtHbUlJtDLstoOUhJYjy2FJGW6TMG4M2v+7SwBEmW/zKB18OZlxVU31k8ikKta13 cEtuhxBL328yBBEp8tYn/ta6U7SO8jplcsAseTB8eWh9/GFGV/8g9C4TU1uGEuY4UU9J+6jqTxh+ gcl5wPgfMGU4j5gcCcMHhL1W6Or7TaRsV0EkiaRkKtXDei4rpVQ8+ndYUr7J1DFk83ltQ6Du8eFO CvNn7/MPAAAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAXsHdGNMBAADZAwAAEAAIAWRvY1Byb3BzL2FwcC54 bWwgogQBKKAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACcU8Fu2zAMvQ/YPxi6N3K6IRsC WcWQYuhhWwPEbc+cTCfCZEmQ2KDZ14+2G8/ZdppP75HU0yMpq5uXzhVHTNkGX4nlohQFehMa6/eV eKg/X30URSbwDbjgsRInzOJGv32jtilETGQxFyzhcyUORHEtZTYH7CAvOO0504bUATFNexna1hq8 Dea5Q0/yuixXEl8IfYPNVZwExai4PtL/ijbB9P7yY32KrKdVjV10QKi/9SfdognUKTlFVR0IXG07 1O84PBG1hT1mvVRyBOoppIY5B0akNgdIYIgHqFcrJWdUfYrRWQPEk9VfrUkhh5aK+8Fu0R9Xcl6i uIUdmudk6aRLJedUfbF+9DEC9pVgnyAeXs1NTO0MONxw87oFl1HJ3wF1h9Avdgu293ek9RENhVRk +5NXey2K75CxH1kljpAseBJj2UgG7GKmpGtLjrUnPsB52Rzb973JEVwWDmTwwPjS3XBDvm+5N/qH 2eXc7OBhtDqzM3d2vuMP1U3oInier5wQD/hHfoh1uO0fxusML4OzpT9ZOuwiGN7Jh4v1zxJqx1Fs eJ/TSqaAuuMGkuvl+azfY3Ou+TvRP6jH8U/Vy9Wi5G94QecYv4PpF9K/AAAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYA CAAAACEAlLxPAXgBAAD7AgAAEQAIAWRvY1Byb3BzL2NvcmUueG1sIKIEASigAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAjJLPT8IwFIDvJv4PS++j2whEl20kaDgYSEzEaLyV9gGV9UfawuC/ t9tguMjB23t9X7++vjabHEUZHMBYrmSO4kGEApBUMS43OXpfzsIHFFhHJCOlkpCjE1g0Ke7vMqpT qgy8GqXBOA428CZpU6pztHVOpxhbugVB7MAT0hfXygjifGo2WBO6IxvASRSNsQBHGHEE18JQd0Z0 VjLaKfXelI2AUQwlCJDO4ngQ4yvrwAh7c0NT+UUK7k4abqKXYkcfLe/AqqoG1bBBff8x/lzM35qr hlzWs6KAiozR1HFXQpHha+gju199A3Xtcpf4mBogTpniZU9kMCWlUIYHc7IypEEv5XrwOzhVyjDr Jb3MYwwsNVw7/5ztEb0FT5fEuoV/3zUHNj3dPO0vVW80cOD1LymShujS7DzytkNggR9V2g72UvkY Pj0vZ6hIongcRo9hMlzGj+lolEbRV91kb/9VKM4N/M+YRF7XN14E7Zz637X4AQAA//8DAFBLAwQU AAYACAAAACEAYEJiP1UMAACveAAADwAAAHdvcmQvc3R5bGVzLnhtbOSdW3PbuhHH3zvT78DRU/uQ yLJlO84c54yvtds48Ymc5hkiIQvHJKHDS2z30xcASYnUEhQX3HrmTPMSi9T+AGL3v8Dypl9+fYlC 7ydPUiHj09Hk/d7I47EvAxE/no6+P1y/+zDy0ozFAQtlzE9Hrzwd/frpr3/55fljmr2GPPUUIE4/ Rv7paJllq4/jceovecTS93LFY7VzIZOIZepj8jiOWPKUr975MlqxTMxFKLLX8f7e3tGoxCR9KHKx ED6/lH4e8Tgz9uOEh4oo43QpVmlFe+5De5ZJsEqkz9NUHXQUFryIiXiNmUwBKBJ+IlO5yN6rgyl7 ZFDKfLJn/orCDeAQB9gHgKOU4xCHJWKcvkb8ZeRF/sfbx1gmbB4qkjokT/XKM+DRJ+XNQPqXfMHy MEv1x+Q+KT+Wn8x/1zLOUu/5I0t9IR5ULxQqEop6cxanYqT2cJZmZ6lgrTuX+o/WPX6a1Tafi0CM xrrF9D9q508Wno7296stF7oHjW0hix+rbTx+931W70lt01xxT0cseTc704bj8sCK/2uHu9r+ZBpe MV+Ydtgi4ypQJ0d7GhoKrYv9w5Pqw7dcjzDLM1k2YgDF/2vsGIy4il8VzbNCVGovX3yW/hMPZpna cToybamN32/vEyETJZzT0YlpU22c8UjciCDgce2L8VIE/MeSx99THmy2/3Ztgr/c4Ms8Vn8fHE9N FIRpcPXi85WWktobM+2TL9og1N/OxaZxY/5HBZuUnmizX3Km84k32UaY7qMQ+9oirR1tOzPfOnbz LVRDB2/V0PStGjp8q4aO3qqh47dq6MNbNWQw/8uGRBzwl0KIsBlA3cWxqBHNsYgNzbFoCc2xSAXN sSgBzbEEOppjiWM0xxKmCE4mfVsU1oL9wBLt3dzdc4Qbd/eU4MbdPQO4cXcnfDfu7vzuxt2dzt24 u7O3G3d3ssZzi6WWd6tkFmeDVbaQMotlxr2MvwynsVixTJFFw9OTHk9IDpIAU2S2ciIeTPOZ+bw7 QoxI3efzTJdznlx4C/GYJ6o2H9pxHv/koaqSPRYEikcITHiWJ5YRcYnphC94wmOfUwY2HVRXgl6c R3OC2FyxRzIWjwPi4auIJElhHdCqfl5qkQiCoI6Yn8jhXZOMLD98FunwsdIQ7zwPQ07E+kITYoY1 vDYwmOGlgcEMrwwMZnhhUPMZ1RCVNKKRKmlEA1bSiMatiE+qcStpRONW0ojGraQNH7cHkYUmxddX HZP+5+4uQqlPiw/ux0w8xkwtAIZPN+U5U++eJewxYaulp89Kt2Prx4xt51wGr94DxZy2JlGt602I XKijFnE+fEAbNCpxrXlE8lrziAS25g2X2J1aJusF2g1NPTPL51mraA2pl2hnLMyLBe1wtbFseIRt BHAtkpRMBu1Yggj+opez2p0UmW/Ty+Ed27CGy2o7K5F2r0QS9DKU/hNNGr55XfFElWVPg0nXMgzl Mw/oiLMskUWs1SW/b1zSS/JX0WrJUmFqpQai/1RfXVD37thq8AHdh0zENH67ehcxEXp0K4ibh7vP 3oNc6TJTDwwN8FxmmYzImOWZwL/94PO/03TwTBXB8SvR0Z4RnR4ysAtBMMkUJBkQkdQyU8SCZA41 vH/x17lkSUBDu094cQ9LxomIMxatikUHgbZUXnxW+YdgNWR4/2aJ0OeFqET1QAKrnTZM8/nv3B+e 6r5Ij+TM0Nc8M+cfzVLXWNPhhi8TGrjhSwTjTTU96PglONgGbvjBNnBUB3sRsjQV1kuozjyqw614 1Mc7vPgreTKUySIP6QawApKNYAUkG0IZ5lGcUh6x4REesOFRHy9hyBgewSk5w/tHIgIyZxgYlScM jMoNBkblAwMjdcDwO3RqsOG36dRgw+/VKWBES4AajCrOSKd/oqs8NRhVnBkYVZwZGFWcGRhVnB1c enyxUItguimmhqSKuRqSbqKJMx6tZMKSVyLkVcgfGcEJ0oJ2n8iFfrhBxsVN3ARIfY46JFxsFzgq J//gc7KuaRZlvwjOiLIwlJLo3NpmwjGWzXvXdpmZJzkGd+E+ZD5fyjDgieWY7LaqXp4Vj2Vsd990 o9dpz8/icZl5s+X6bH8dc7S307Iq2BtmuxtsG/Oj6nmWNrM7Hog8qjoKH6Y4OuhvbCK6YTzdbbxZ STQsD3tawjaPdltuVskNy+OelrDNDz0tjU4bll16uGTJU2sgHHfFz7rGswTfcVcUrY1bm+0KpLVl Wwged0VRQyreme/rqwXQO/00Y7fvJx67PUZFdgpGTnZKb13ZEV0C+8Z/Cj2zY5KmaW999wTI+2YR 3Stz/pbL4rx944JT/4e6btXCKU6518o56H/hqpFl7OPYO93YEb3zjh3ROwHZEb0ykdUclZLslN65 yY7onaTsCHS2gjMCLltBe1y2gvYu2QpSXLLVgFWAHdF7OWBHoIUKEWihDlgp2BEooQJzJ6FCClqo EIEWKkSghQoXYDihQnucUKG9i1AhxUWokIIWKkSghQoRaKFCBFqoEIEWquPa3mruJFRIQQsVItBC hQi0UM16cYBQoT1OqNDeRaiQ4iJUSEELFSLQQoUItFAhAi1UiEALFSJQQgXmTkKFFLRQIQItVIhA C7V41NBdqNAeJ1Ro7yJUSHERKqSghQoRaKFCBFqoEIEWKkSghQoRKKECcyehQgpaqBCBFipEoIVq LhYOECq0xwkV2rsIFVJchAopaKFCBFqoEIEWKkSghQoRaKFCBEqowNxJqJCCFipEoIUKEV3xWV6i tN1mP8Gf9bTesd//0lXZqW/1R7nrqIP+qKpXdlb/ZxHOpXzyWh88PDD1Rj+ImIdCmlPUlsvqda65 JQJ14fPrRfcTPnX6wJculc9CmGumAD7tawnOqUy7Qr5uCYq8aVek1y3BqnPalX3rlmAanHYlXaPL 6qYUNR0B4640UzOeWMy7snXNHA5xV46uGcIR7srMNUM4wF35uGZ46OnkvG192HOcjtb3lwJCVzjW CMd2QldYQl9V6RgKo6/T7IS+3rMT+rrRTkD504rBO9aOQnvYjnJzNZQZ1tXuQrUTsK6GBCdXA4y7 qyHK2dUQ5eZqmBixroYErKvdk7Od4ORqgHF3NUQ5uxqi3FwNpzKsqyEB62pIwLp64IRsxbi7GqKc XQ1Rbq6GizusqyEB62pIwLoaEpxcDTDuroYoZ1dDlJurQZWMdjUkYF0NCVhXQ4KTqwHG3dUQ5exq iOpytTmL0nA1ysM1c9wirGaIm5BrhrjkXDN0qJZq1o7VUo3gWC1BX1U+x1VLdafZCX29Zyf0daOd gPKnFYN3rB2F9rAd5eZqXLXU5mp3odoJWFfjqiWrq3HVUqercdVSp6tx1ZLd1bhqqc3VuGqpzdXu ydlOcHI1rlrqdDWuWup0Na5asrsaVy21uRpXLbW5Glcttbl64IRsxbi7GlctdboaVy3ZXY2rltpc jauW2lyNq5baXI2rlqyuxlVLna7GVUudrsZVS3ZX46qlNlfjqqU2V+OqpTZX46olq6tx1VKnq3HV UqercdXSnTIRBK+AmkUsyTy698XdsHSZMcTLCcfPjR+Y0mDz+23q+5nqlX7HeO2BoKB4x2oJNF+8 DdY/BKWNdTe88ie3ys2mt+UF0aJFYwib8peqLb98O5SlqfItr+vHlMw7XrcbtrwK1nRk4+Lq2+V4 bsar+F5jtDr7nemQ6uizCbnOMSqi0tbBk1Jmu3qo+jMPix8lU3/cxoECPJc/yFX0NHhhBUrtv+Bh eMeKb8uV/ashX2TF3smeeSnA1v558X47q31iEqEVMG52pvhY/jCaZbyLN96XV+itIanV3jLc5naR oSNt71tDLn6eqqExytru3z9zFvNQTkAPyx1epXKVFbZ2TS6UTrZVpcY5Fdrh5pt7eyfT6cllmcFa f6XvdHSWCBV55yHzTd4xP8LX3GqsfZ0oK/D19Z76V/qt+pG8gUPxe3FY+2Aoyh1elYhrQ1HZEA3F OcuXLE+9E7OML0eithEOxIers7PLcxPN+ml3M5ucjpiZS8zhmc0PQv+I3jqq1j9aWNwusXsIGxmx RzSZ4bBGlLcZrTlTgfxVzxv1hNnMqtb4K4fyzxpv5WEc2AaqugkGHvkBUbjdyVjqPqtFiLL9yWrD AXbBMbm6PL4s7uCCoVe2u4m0E7PQpIu0hvCsgh0aaeuU8H8t5yLcbFFKpOZyNP6MMVz9lX76LwAA AP//AwBQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEA36TSbFoBAAAgBQAAEwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAW0NvbnRl bnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQAekRq37wAAAE4CAAALAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJMD AABfcmVscy8ucmVsc1BLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQDWZLNR9AAAADEDAAAcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALMG AAB3b3JkL19yZWxzL2RvY3VtZW50LnhtbC5yZWxzUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhANAeKPfcAgAAMQsA ABEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA6QgAAHdvcmQvZG9jdW1lbnQueG1sUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAGY6vBQk BgAAjxoAABUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA9AsAAHdvcmQvdGhlbWUvdGhlbWUxLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAI AAAAIQCejGvL0AMAADUKAAARAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEsSAAB3b3JkL3NldHRpbmdzLnhtbFBLAQIt ABQABgAIAAAAIQCklWIcVgIAAHAIAAASAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEoWAAB3b3JkL2ZvbnRUYWJsZS54 bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAk3bWSRgBAABAAgAAFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADQGAAAd29yZC93ZWJT ZXR0aW5ncy54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAXsHdGNMBAADZAwAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAaGgAA ZG9jUHJvcHMvYXBwLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQCUvE8BeAEAAPsCAAARAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ACMdAABkb2NQcm9wcy9jb3JlLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQBgQmI/VQwAAK94AAAPAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAANIfAAB3b3JkL3N0eWxlcy54bWxQSwUGAAAAAAsACwDBAgAAVCwAAAAA");

    }
```